# NSTimer does not call selector after assigned time interval. iOS

Tags: ios, nstimer, uipagecontrol

I am having a banners array and displaying it in my custom cell. When user clicks on banner, I push a `detailViewController` and opens in-app browser.

I am changing banners after every 5 seconds. For that, I am using `NSTimer` to schedule the selector call. Everything works great.... Until, user clicks on banner and come back from `detailViewController`. When user comes back, NSTimer behaves really weird. It changes first banner after 5 seconds (as assigned) and then next banner is changed after 1 second and so on.

Her is the code I am using:

```
#pragma mark - User Methods
-(void) resetBannerRotationTimer {
    [self.bannerTimer invalidate];
    self.bannerTimer = nil;
    self.timeInterval = 5.0f;
    self.bannerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(rotateBanner) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.timeInterval = self.bannerTimer.timeInterval;

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.bannerTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

}
```

**rotateBanner:**

```
-(void) rotateBanner {
    BannerCell *bannerCell = (BannerCell *)[self.dealsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [bannerCell updateBanner];
}
```

In my `updateBanner` method, I am handeling `UIPageControl` to change pages. (I don't think that code needs to be posted).

I am calling `resetBannerRotationTimer` method in `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: How many times your `resetBannerRotationTimer` is called? I think you should use `scheduledTimerWithtimeInterval`. then you don't need to add timer to runLoop.

Comment: Code looks fine. Keep a breakpoint in your _resetBannerRotationTimer_ method. See if timer object is valid. In debugger window use __po [NSRunLoop currentLoop]__ to print the content and verify the properties of timer object. See if anything wrong there.

Comment: I have tried `scheduledTimerWithtimeInterval`, it is changing banner after 5 seconds and then 3 seconds. Still, time interval is 5 seconds.

Comment: I have updated my `resetBannerRotationTimer` method as well.

Comment: Got the issue. My timer was not invalidated when user clicked on banner. It should not create the issue but still it was. I set my timer nil on click and its working.

Answer (score -1):

i think you are missing to fire your timer

add this line after timer scheduling

```
[self.bannerTimer fire];
```

Comment: -1 . I am using `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` so I don't have to explicitly fire the timer. If that was the issue, then my selector will never call.